# R - kill based on age

Tags: r, list, loops

I'm trying to set up something that feels like it should be simple, but I can't figure out a solution.  I wrote a stripped down version of my code with an attempt at explaining it along the way.

Basically, I want to create a group of "children" each generation.  Then, add 1 to age per generation and delete the list entry when age > 3.  The code almost works - I think the problem has to do with calling the length of fl and then removing lines from the list, but I'm not sure.  The end result (fl) should not have any entries larger than 3 if it's working properly.

Code:

```
#NUMBER OF PARENTS TO START WITH
parents <- 10
#NUMBER OF GENERATIONS TO RUN
generations <- 5
#NUMBER OF CHILDREN TO CREATE EACH GENERATION
children <- 5
#AGE TO KILL
death <- 3

pl <- list()
cl <- list()
fl <- list()
kl <- list()

#CREATE PARENTS
for (i2 in 1:parents) {
pl[[i2]] <- 0
}

fl <- pl


#START GEN LOOP

i3 <- 0
while (i3 < generations) {
i3 <- i3 + 1


#CREATE CHILDREN
for (i5 in 1:children) {
cl[[i5]] <- 0
}

#ADD CHILDREN TO FINAL LIST
fl <- c(fl, cl)

#ADD 1 TO AGE
for (i6 in 1:length(fl)) {
fl[[i6]] <- fl[[i6]] + 1
}


###PROBLEM###
#KILL BASED ON AGE
i4 <- 0
while (i4 < length(fl)) {
i4 <- i4 + 1
if (fl[[i4]] > death) {

#ADD TO KILL LIST FOR DEBUGGING
kl <- c(kl, fl[[i4]])

#REMOVE FROM fl
fl <- fl[-c(i4), drop=FALSE]
}
}

#CLOSE GEN LOOP
}

fl
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the first iteration of your loop, your parents are 0 and so are the children that you add (you add age after the children are added to `fl`). Is this intentional?

Comment: @kungfujam it looks like all of their ages get incremented at once, after adding them to `fl`.

Comment: Yes - intentional.  I want them to age after the reproducing has happened (the end of the generation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop the element from the list, you aren't adjusting `i4` accordingly. Try this:

```
  ###FIXED###
  #KILL BASED ON AGE
  i4 <- 0
  while (i4 < length(fl)) {
    i4 <- i4 + 1
    if (fl[[i4]] > death) {
      #ADD TO KILL LIST FOR DEBUGGING
      kl <- c(kl, fl[[i4]])

      #REMOVE FROM fl
      fl <- fl[-c(i4), drop=FALSE]
      i4 <- i4 - 1 #                <------ added this line
    }
  }
```

Also your code is fairly nonstandard (and kind of hard to read). This isn't code review, but I would at least suggest using `for` instead of `while`... I think your typical R user will be much more comfortable with those. I'm not sure `lapply` is actually the right solution here; imo it loses some of the literal resonance of a loop. But I would *highly* recommend writing functions instead of just a wall of loops. Then you can write something readable like

```
life <- function(n_parents, n_children, death_age, n_generations) {
  fl <- as.list(rep(0, n_parents))
  for (i in 1:n_generations) {
    fl <- spawn_children(fl, n_children)
    fl <- lapply(fl, `+`, 1) # increment ages by 1
    fl <- kill_old_people(fl, death_age)
  }
  fl
}

life(
  n_parents = 10,
  n_children = 5,
  death_age = 3,
  n_generations = 5
)
```

Comment: I honestly appreciate the suggestions and critique.  I'm self taught in R and I'm so used to using loops from other languages that it's just my go to solution.  I really need to better learn how to use lapply and for instead of the while loops.  Thank you also for providing a fix to my actual code and a (much) more eloquent rewrite of the whole thing!

Answer (score 2):

Typically when using R you want to avoid looping when you can. It's slow and there are functions you can use to avoid it. I think your original code is not working as, because you are looping, you are removing an element, then the indexes will change, then for the next iteration you end up removing the wrong element. I've altered your code, see what you think:

```
#NUMBER OF PARENTS TO START WITH
parents <- 10
#NUMBER OF GENERATIONS TO RUN
generations <- 5
#NUMBER OF CHILDREN TO CREATE EACH GENERATION
children <- 5
#AGE TO KILL
death <- 3

pl <- list()
cl <- list()
fl <- list()
kl <- list()

#CREATE PARENTS
# for (i2 in 1:parents) {
#     pl[[i2]] <- 0
# }
fl <- pl <- as.list(rep(0, parents))

# fl <- pl


#START GEN LOOP

i3 <- 0
while (i3 < generations) {
    i3 <- i3 + 1


    #CREATE CHILDREN
#     for (i5 in 1:children) {
#         cl[[i5]] <- 0
#     }

    cl <- as.list(rep(0, children))

    #ADD CHILDREN TO FINAL LIST
    fl <- c(fl, cl)

    #ADD 1 TO AGE
#     for (i6 in 1:length(fl)) {
#         fl[[i6]] <- fl[[i6]] + 1
#     }
    fl <- lapply(fl, function(x) x+1)

    ###PROBLEM###
    #KILL BASED ON AGE
#     i4 <- 0
#     while (i4 < length(fl)) {
#         i4 <- i4 + 1
#         if (fl[[i4]] > death) {
#             
#             #ADD TO KILL LIST FOR DEBUGGING
#             kl <- c(kl, fl[[i4]])
#             
#             #REMOVE FROM fl
#             fl <- fl[-c(i4), drop=FALSE]
#         }
#     }
    fl <- fl[fl <= death]    

    #CLOSE GEN LOOP
}

fl
```

`lapply` is your friend

Comment: Thank you - your solution works and the code is much simpler.  So that I understand for the future, could you explain how "fl <- fl[fl <= death] " works?  I'm not familiar with this method.

Comment: @jdfinch3 in R, you can subset using a logical vector. Consider `a <- 98:100`. Then `a[1]` returns the same thing as `a[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)]`. On top of that, `<=` is vectorized, so `5:7 <= 5` will return `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)`, so you could in principle use `a[5:7 <= 1]` to get the same result as `a[1]`. This is actually a pretty common trick, and it saves you the trouble of writing, say, `a[which(5:7 <= 5)]`, where in this case `which(5:7 <= 5)` will return `1`.

Comment: No problem @jdfinch3 and thanks @ssdecontrol for stepping in. Enter `?'logical'` into your R console for more info.